# Gsub ignore string interpolation

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm trying to gsub the exact characters `#{}` without ruby treating them as string interpolation.

For example:

`"Test string".gsub("string", "#{cat}")` would need to become the literal string `Test #{cat}` and not the variable.

Comment: From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings): _"Interpolation may be disabled by escaping the “#” character or using single-quote strings: `'#{1 + 1}'`"_

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes. Double quotes are used for interpolation; `#{}` is ignored inside single quotes:

```
x = 'Test string'.gsub('string', '#{cat}')
=> "Test \#{cat}"

puts x
Test #{cat}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that this has nothing to do with `gsub`, only the string that is the second argument. Whatever that string is (after interpolation, of course), it will be the replacement for each substring `"string"`.

Here are a few ways the second argument could be modified. All return `"\#{cat}"` and `puts "\#{cat}"` displays  `#{cat}`.

*Use single quotes<sup>1</sup>*

```
'\#{cat}'
```

*Escape the pound sign or left brace*

```
"\#{cat}"
"#\{cat}"
```

*Combine two strings*

```
"#" + "{cat}"
"#" << "{cat}"
"#".concat("{cat}")
"#" "{cat}"
```

*Use string interpolation on the pound character*

```
"#{'#'}{cat}"
```

<sup>1. Taken from @anothermh's answer.</sup>

Comment: You can even omit the `+` and use `"#" "{cat}"`.

Comment: @Stefan, that strikes me as bizarre, but yes, it works. I found the [doc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html). It's under `Strings`. One of the examples given is `%q{a} 'b' "c" #=> "abc"`. (Note that `'b' "c" %q{a}` doesn't work because `%` is interpreted as the method [String#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-25), which treats it's receiver as a format specification.) I understand this has it's roots in C. I added that to my answer.